# Java Regex is not matching

Tags: java, regex

I am using a regex that would basically regex for the following URL:

```
http://foo.org/query?id=234934&apiKey=FNSJDS3442939
```

The regex is:

```
^(http://foo.org/)?(query)?([?])?(id)?([=])?([0-9\\&]*)?(apiKey\\=)?([0-9a-z-A-Z])$
```

While using an online tester, I can verify that the pattern does match. I am using [this](https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html#ad-output). But when I run it in my code, it does not match. In fact, when I am using the online regex tester, it says it sees the pattern but it is not a match. I am assuming the regex tester is testing using the matches() method for `java.util.Regex.Matcher`. Can someone tell me why this is not an exact match?

UPDATE:

Still can't figure this out with the suggestions so I will post my method:

```
public void regexHttp(List<String> url) {
    String badURL = "^(http://foo.org/)?(query)?([?])?(id)?([=])?([0-9\\&]*)?(apiKey\\=)?([0-9a-z-A-Z]+)$";
    String badURLTwo = "^(http://f.oo/)?([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$";
    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(badURL);
    Pattern s = Pattern.compile(badURLTwo);
    for(int a = 0; a < url.size(); a++)
    {
        Matcher m = r.matcher(url.get(a));
        Matcher n = s.matcher(url.get(a));
          if (m.find()) {
              url.remove(url.get(a));
           }    
         // else
            //  if (url.get(a).matches(badURLTwo))
             // {
                //  url.remove(url.get(a));
              //}
    }
    send.randomizeLinks(url);
}
```

Both regexes I am testing does not pass.

Comment: Use `Java.lang.URL` class to parse an URL not a regex

Comment: Remove all ``\\`` from your pattern. You do not need those. And an unescaped `.` will match any char but a line break char.

Comment: Not even sure why this is downvoted..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex :

```
^(http://foo.org/)?(query)?([?])?(id)?([=])?([0-9\\&]*)?(apiKey\\=)?([0-9a-z-A-Z]+)$
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------^
```

You are missing `+` for that your patter not match because it contain more than one character or number.

---

[ideone demo](https://ideone.com/ALP1F3)

---

I tried this :

```
String str = "http://foo.org/query?id=234934&apiKey=FNSJDS3442939";
System.out.println(str.matches("^(http://foo.org/)?(query)?([?])?(id)?([=])?([0-9\\&]*)?(apiKey\\=)?([0-9a-z-A-Z]+)$"));
```

and the output is :

```
true
```

Comment: did you check the [ideone demo](https://ideone.com/ALP1F3) or can you please share your code?

Comment: Yes I did check it out and tried it that way but it didnt work.

Comment: Yikes, still not working.. I dont get why it is not matching.. I verified it via online testers

Comment: what tester you mean @ryekayo ?

Comment: Thanks but sorry to go back and forth on this but yes the problem still exists. I will update my question :)

Comment: @ryekayo i tried to make this `String url = "http://foo.org/query?id=234934&apiKey=FNSJDS3442939";
String badURL = "^(http://foo.org/)?(query)?([?])?(id)?([=])?([0-9\\&]*)?(apiKey\\=)?([0-9a-z-A-Z]+)$";
String badURLTwo = "^(http://f.oo/)?([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(badURL);
Pattern s = Pattern.compile(badURLTwo);

Matcher m = r.matcher(url);
Matcher n = s.matcher(url);
System.out.println(m.find());
System.out.println(n.find());` and it show me `true, false` mean it match the regex that i gives you and not match the second regex is that what you get?

Comment: Yes that seems to be the case.

Comment: so, where is the problem now @ryekayo ?

Comment: Well.. I gotta fix that second regex.. I will see if i can figure it out though.

Comment: The issue is i have a conditional that checks for the badURL and that works but when i try to add a conditional to check for badURLTwo, it breaks both pattern matching.

Comment: so the result is work @ryekayo or still have the problem?